# How to put logo on left and menu on right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'd like to make a header like [this site](http://theme.nileforest.com/html/mazel-v1.4/01_mazel_multiprapose/index.html) or [this site](http://htmlcoder.me/preview/the_project/v.1.3/template/index.html), I mean I want to put logo on left side and menu on right. But my header doesn't float well on [here](https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/header/). I am confused now.

```css
#header-right {
    float: left;
}
#header-right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="container" id="header-inner">
      <div class="row">

      <div id="header-left" class="clearfix">
        <div id="logo" class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/4252154/images/o-EMBLEM-facebook.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo-img" class="logo-img" height="35" width="150">
          </a>
        </div>  <!-- logo  -->
      </div>  <!-- header-left -->

      <div id="header-right">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Apple Juice</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>  <!-- navbar-header -->

      <!-- Global Navigation -->
      <div class="gnav collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown active">
         <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">Home <i></i></a>
         <!-- Dropdown -->
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a class="" href='#'>ジュース <i class=""></i></a>
          <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">オレンジ</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">アップル</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">グレープ</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href='#'>寿司 <i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">マグロ</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">サーモン</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">エンガワ</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
         </li>  <!-- dropdown active-->

         <li class="dropdown">
           <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">items <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a class="" href='#'>スマートフォン <i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Xperia</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Galaxy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href='#'>野菜 <i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">トマト</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">レタス</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">枝豆</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
         </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

         <li class="dropdown">
           <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">order <i></i></a>     
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="" href='#'>自分用</a></li>
         <li><a class="" href='#'>他人用</a></li>
          </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
         </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

             <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">contact <i></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a class="" href='#'>フォーム</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href='#'>電話</a></li>
               </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
            </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

        </ul>  <!-- nav navbar-nav -->
      </div>  <!-- gnav collapse navbar-collapse -->

          </nav>  <!-- navbar navbar-default  -->
        </div>  <!-- header-right -->

        </div>  <!-- clearfix -->
      </div>  <!-- row -->
    </div>  <!-- container -->
  </header>

</div>  <!-- wrapper -->
```

Ah, I usually use `clearfix` in `<div class="row">` or in `<header>` not in `<div id="header-left">`, but I wrote that in `<div id="header-left">`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `.navbar-right` class](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment):

> Align nav links, forms, buttons, or text, using the `.navbar-left` or `.navbar-right` utility classes. Both classes will add a CSS float in the specified direction. For example, to align nav links, put them in a separate `<ul>` with the respective utility class applied.

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="">Right 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Right 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Right 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

#### Update

I've used `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` instead of `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` in your code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="container" id="header-inner">
      <div class="row">

      <div id="header-left" class="clearfix">
        <div id="logo" class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/4252154/images/o-EMBLEM-facebook.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo-img" class="logo-img" height="35" width="150">
          </a>
        </div>  <!-- logo  -->
      </div>  <!-- header-left -->

      <div id="header-right">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Apple Juice</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>  <!-- navbar-header -->

      <!-- Global Navigation -->
      <div class="gnav collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li class="dropdown active">
         <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">Home <i></i></a>
         <!-- Dropdown -->
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a class="" href='#'>ジュース <i class=""></i></a>
          <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">オレンジ</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">アップル</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">グレープ</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href='#'>寿司 <i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">マグロ</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">サーモン</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">エンガワ</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
         </li>  <!-- dropdown active-->

         <li class="dropdown">
           <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">items <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a class="" href='#'>スマートフォン <i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Xperia</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Galaxy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href='#'>野菜 <i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="sub-dropdown">
           <li><a href="#">トマト</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">レタス</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">枝豆</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
         </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

         <li class="dropdown">
           <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">order <i></i></a>     
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="" href='#'>自分用</a></li>
         <li><a class="" href='#'>他人用</a></li>
          </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
         </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

             <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">contact <i></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a class="" href='#'>フォーム</a></li>
                 <li><a class="" href='#'>電話</a></li>
               </ul>  <!-- dropdown-menu -->
            </li>  <!-- dropdown -->

        </ul>  <!-- nav navbar-nav -->
      </div>  <!-- gnav collapse navbar-collapse -->

          </nav>  <!-- navbar navbar-default  -->
        </div>  <!-- header-right -->

        </div>  <!-- clearfix -->
      </div>  <!-- row -->
    </div>  <!-- container -->
  </header>

</div>  <!-- wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1):

your css is wrong please replace one of properties as

```
#header-left {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

This will make sure your left block takes only area that it fits into.